# Set variable equal to search match subsection

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression, search, substitute, functions

Unnecessary Context:

I want to write a function that closes open HTML tags, because [closetag.vim](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=13) seems complicated, and I like to understand all the stuff I run in Vim.
My plan for this is to match the most recent previous `<\w+` segment, grab whatever is `\w+`, and then output `</\1>` at the cursor location when I ran this function.

---

Question:

How do I set a variable in my function equal to the most recent previous instance of `\w\+` that comes after a `<`? I can do the search with `?<\(\w\+\)`, but nothing I've found will honor the capture group usage.

I have found `matches` and `getmatches` in `:help` (and [`searchpos` and `getline` on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30074317/5889131)), but it certainly feels like there should be an easier way than using two builtins together. I know about the search register, but that only contains the literal regex above, not what it has matched to.

It looks like [a similar question was asked 5 months ago](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22989/search-a-pattern-preceding-cursor-position-modify-it-and-insert-the-modified-st) but the only answer is about matching tags on the same line, and I would like to do more. I found [this question that says how to visually highlight the whole match](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/26945/17205), but can't handle capture groups, though it looks like the best method if I give up on the capture group limitation.

**TL;DR:** Is there a simple way to get the contents of a capture group search result into a variable?

Comment: Does submatch not work here or am I missing something?

Comment: From reading the `:help` it looks like that's only valid for substitutions, and I don't plan on changing the text I'm trying to match. If I'm incorrect, I'd love to see an answer that shows what you mean!

Comment: Hm, maybe you could use the 'n' flag to not substitute and set a variable? I’ll have to dig

Comment: **Note:** for cases where you **do** want to immediately do a substitution `:s^^\=submatch(0).'</'.submatch(1).'>'^g` is adequate. For cases where you **do not** want to do an immediate substitution, the problem is a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up combining [these](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/26945/17205) [three](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17074/highlighting-a-search-capture-group) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19762869/5889131) to make my function.

No, there is not a way to get just a capture group from a search, but if your goal is just one capture group, you can use `\zs` and/or `\ze` as your group start and end points to determine highlighting and where your cursor lands.

```
" Ex: change <\(\w\+\) to to <\zs\w\+\ze (replace capture group with \zs and \ze)
function! GetMatch(pattern)
    let l:cursor_pos = getpos(".")
    let @/ = a:pattern
    " preserve old register content
    let savereg = @f
    " empty "f in case we don't find a match
    " if we skipped this, "f would keep whatever was in there before.
    let @f = ""
    normal "fygN
    let match = @f
    " restore register content
    let @f = l:savereg
    call setpos(".", l:cursor_pos)
    echo l:match
    return l:match
endfunction
```

I get the initial `cursor_pos`ition and set the `/`search register.

From there, I can temporarily grab the results of my search into an arbitrary register (f for function is what I'm going with), then set a variable to hold the contents of that register and then reset the `cursor_pos`ition to where it originally was.

I'm eventually going to hardcode the pattern to search for `<\zs\w\+` but this was useful for testing purposes, and should showcase how to do this for anyone searching.

Comment: Great answer! A related question came up recently and `gn` was the solution there too... A couple of nitpicks: 1) Use `:normal!` to avoid any problems if any of `y` or `gN` are remapped. 2) When you save and restore the register, use `getregtype()` to save its type, then restore it with `setreg()` which takes an additional argument with the type. Otherwise saving/restoring a register coming from a visual block will break it. (Oh and a tiny minor one, in `<\zs\w\+\ze`, you don't need the `\ze` if that's the end of the pattern anyways... Just the `\zs` is enough to skip `>`.)

Comment: Yeah, I link to the `gn` answer in the question - it was very helpful. I know that only `\zs` is necessary, I use it that way in the last sentence of my answer, but I figured for people who want to "lift and shift" for their purposes I should include both. 1. That is good to know about `normal!`, I was unaware, thanks! for `getregtype` I'd need another variable to store the type, right? There's no way to save a register and its type in one command?

Comment: I’d probably have just implemented the searchpos/getline version you rejected in the question, but this is a really nifty solution! +1

Comment: @Rich, I'd be interested in seeing another way of doing this, but no worries if you're busy. I was looking for the shortest way of doing this, but the fact that I have to save and restore the register contents and type means this way isn't as concise as I originally wanted.

Comment: @jeremysprofile Yes, use two separate variables, one for the contents (either use `@f` or `getreg('f')` as they're equivalent) and the second for the type. The `setreg()` call takes three arguments, the first with the name, second with the value, and the third (optional) argument is the type, which you can take directly from `getregtype()`.